# Overload resolution fails to find `operator+` from a different namespace

Tags: c++

In the following code example, we have two classes `X` and `Y`, both implicitly convertible to `n1::Base`. `Base` supports addition, so I thought `X` and `Y` should also support it via conversion to `Base`. Instead, they only support it if their template parameter is `Base` (even though that template parameter isn't used anywhere).

Can anyone explain why that is? Bonus points if you can point me to a part of the standard or link the relevant cppreference.com article.

It would be intuitive to me if both `X` and `Y` supported addition in all or in no cases. But I don't understand why they only compile with the appropriate template parameter. I'm happy to clarify more if you're not sure why this is confusing to me. I'm guessing it has something to do with ADL ([argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)), but I'm not sure.

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/xe3enE9Tf

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace n1 {
struct Base {};

int operator+(Base const&, int other) { return other; }
}

using n1::Base;

// Uncommenting this would fix the error below.
// using n1::operator+;

template <class = Base>
struct X {
    Base b;
    operator Base() { return b; }
};

template <class = void>
struct Y {
    Base b;
    operator Base() { return b; }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << Base{} + 3;
    std::cout << X{} + 3; // Compiles
    std::cout << Y<Base>{} + 3; // Also compiles
    std::cout << Y{} + 3; // Doesn't compile
    std::cout << X<void>{} + 3; // Also doesn't compile
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It feels silly to answer my question immediately but as soon as I read more about ADL, I found the line. From cppreference (emphasis mine):

> ...
>
> Otherwise, for every argument in a function call expression its type is examined to determine the associated set of namespaces and classes that it will add to the lookup.
>
> ...
>
> 3) For arguments whose type is a **class template specialization**, in addition to the class rules, the following types are examined and their associated classes and namespaces are added to the set.
>
> a) The types of all **template arguments** provided for type template parameters (skipping non-type template parameters and skipping template template parameters).

In short, the namespace of the template parameter to `X` and `Y` is added to the associated set of namespaces. If the parameter is from `n1`, `n1::operator+` becomes visible.

Comment: That's the way it is sometimes. Writing up the question often shakes loose the bit of information you needed, but not always before you post the question.

Comment: And here's the formal rule: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep#3.2   (cppreference is just a paraphrase)